What is the expected number of triangles in a uniformly selected simple p-regular graph?
If we select a random graph from the set of all simple graphs with n labeled vertices, such that each vertex has degree p, what is the expected number of triangles in the resulting simple graph?
I'm equivalently asking the probability that any 3 points in the graph form a cycle, since the answer then comes from linearity of expectation, but I'm not sure how to compute this either. I can compute the probability that a given vertex connects to two other specific vertices ( (n-3)/(n-1 choose 3) ), but I can't figure out the probability of the third edge, since this probability doesn't seem to treat edges independently (the condition that the graph must be a p-regular graph throws things off, I think).
I would appreciate any insight on this. I think I have an empirical average of around 1.32 when p = 3 and n goes to infinity, but I don't have a lot of insight, and am generally looking for a non-limiting average based on fixed values of p and n (or if this is intractable, then a limiting average as n goes to infinity.)

The answer certainly depends on $p$. For some cases (at the very least, when $p$ is constant as $n \to \infty$) the distribution approaches Poisson, but you need to include more detail before we can certainly say whether that's the case.

The answer does depend on p, I am asking for the expectation as a function of p and n.

Relevant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model
